# How to get the calculated size of subviews in UITableViewCell or UICollectionViewCell

Tags: uitableview, ios8, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to add gradient layer to `UILabel` in a custom `UITableViewCell` (or collectionViewCell). I set some constraints to `UILabel` in interface builder so it gets resized according to the content. But I don't know how to get the correct frame size of subviews of cells.

I tried `layoutSubviews` but it is called multiple times, twice in my case. So it adds two gradient layers, first one for not calculated frame, one for calculated frame.

I tried `cellForItemAtIndexPath` for both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`. It doesn't work either.

How, or when do I get the correct frame size of subviews in `UITableViewCell` or `UICollectionView`?

Answer (score 0):

You can always resize added gradient layer or remove it and add again in `layoutSubviews` .

Comment: It is not consistent. Some cells use not calculated frame, some cells use calculated frame. Also the change is visible; I see gradient layer moving

Comment: So in that case try using `UIView` with only one layer, which is your gradient layer class (`CAGradientLayer` as I suppose). Layer for view is returned by `UIView` `layerClass` method https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/layerClass . Set this view as `backgroundView` of your table cell https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/backgroundView and it should resize automatically

Comment: Adding as background view won't work for me, because I wan't to add gradient to one of the subviews (which is `UILabel`) I don't need the size of the `UITableViewCell`, I need it's subviews'

Comment: So use your own class derived from `UILabel` and in `layoutSubview` after calling super resize added `CALayer` with gradient